# Gitlab CI: Execute own Script in Kaniko Job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, busybox, kaniko

I have the following Job to build Images in my gitlab-ci.yml

```
dockerize:
  stage: containerize
  before_script:
   - eval $($CONTEXT_SCRIPT_PATH)
  environment:
    name: $CONTEXT
    url: XXX
  image:
      name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug-v0.23.0
      entrypoint: [""]  
  script:
      - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL\":{\"username\":\"$CI_DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
      - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/portal/frontend:$CONTEXT-$CI_PIPELINE_IID --build-arg VERSION_TAG=$CONTEXT-$CI_PIPELINE_IID --build-arg COMMIT_TIME=$COMMIT_TIME
      - echo "Pushed to Registry - $CI_DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/portal/frontend:$CONTEXT-$CI_PIPELINE_IID"
  retry: 2
```

In the before_script section the env $CONTEXT gets set.
$CONTEXT_SCRIPT_PATH is set in a global variables section:

```
variables:
  CONTEXT_SCRIPT_PATH: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Scripts/get_context.sh"
```

But if the Job is running, it can't find the script.

```
/busybox/sh: eval: line 90: /builds/portal/portal-frontend/Scripts/get_context.sh: not found
```

It works in other Jobs, so is Kaniko running in some separate environment? How do I specify the right Path?

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: If i remember right we didn't fixed it. Instead we had a separate job for every environment

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but for anyone who stumbles across this:

The script file must already exist in the **current Job**.

Either:

- It exists in the project git repository and is automatically added by `git clone` before each job
- It is manually created during the job - `echo 'my script stuff' > $CONTEXT_SCRIPT_PATH`
- By default track all untracked files as artifacts - `default: { artifacts: untracked } }`
- Or included as an artifact:

```yaml
---
default: { variables: { CONTEXT_SCRIPT_PATH: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Scripts/get_context.sh" } }

build-first: 
  stage: build
  artifacts: { paths: "$CONTEXT_SCRIPT_PATH" }  # tell gitlab to artifact the script

build-second:
  stage: build
  dependencies: [ build-first ]  # run this stage after build-first succeeded
  before_script: [ "eval $($CONTEXT_SCRIPT_PATH)" ]
```

**NOTES:**

- global sections are deprecated- use `default` and put `variables` within, as shown above
- If artifacts from a previous job in the same stage are required, use `dependencies` and reference the required stage
- If you do not use `dependencies`, **all** artifacts from **previous** stages are passed to each job

References (GitLab): [CI Keyword Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml) [Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts), [Dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies), [Default](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#default)